# Two Device Connect to server by Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Hi guy I just need to ask if there is a way to connect two different device to the server at the same time by Bluetooth.

or is there a way to let both device Connected by one on standby and the other is talk

Answer (score 0):

yes you can connect two different devices by making a bluetooth server , here is a sample app Named as Bluetooth chat    https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat

In which two devices are connected with each other and doing chatting through message box .
And If you want to connect more than two devices from One devices like as a ***Master And Slave*** 
use BluetoothServerSocket  [[2]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html from that you can connect Upto 7 devices from One device .